# How to read integers from a specific point of a .txt file using C?

Tags: c, file

I need to implement a game using the C language where a functionality is to able the player to save the game to play later. 
A requirement is to save the data of the game on a .txt file in the next way:
1) the number of players in the first row;
2) the cards on the table in the second row, identified by player 0 and the existent cards.
3) the next information for each player: number of player, if it is a real player or bot (1 if it's bot, 0 if it's real), the name of the player, the points and the cards in the hand. See the example below of the format of how I need to store the data on the .txt file:

```
2\n
0:T;23,43,45\n
1:0;John;23:12,32,44,43\n
2:1;BOT1;34:43,54,53,45\n
EOF
```

Now, I don't have any idea of how to store, for example the cards of player 1 (named John) in a structure player[0].cards[7], when the player is loading the game after this .txt file. 
How can i save the name of player 1 (John) into player[0].name and then save the name of the second player (BOT1) into player[1].name.

I've been trying to solve this for days, but I'm not being successful. Can someone help me to understand how to store a specific number/string from a specific position on a .txt file back into my code? How can I make my code read the numbers, for example 12,32,44,43 and store it the proper array. How can I make my code navigate the file with all the lines, the ":", ";" and ",".

I'm not asking for the solution. I'm just want someone to enlight my mind so that I can find the proper way to do this. Any help is welcome. 
Thank you.

Comment: It seems like plain `fprintf` (for writing) and `fscanf` (for reading) could be used for all your needs.

Comment: have a look at `fgets`, `strtok`, and `sscanf`; these three in combination should be sufficient.

Comment: @StephanLechner thanks for the replay, but my problem was more like: how can I write a piece of code which knows that he needs to store the numbers after the second ":" until the "\n" in a struct player[i].cards[j]. And this for all the lines related to players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you use `fgets` to read the file line by line;
Then you can parse each line and each part of such a line separately.
As far as the list of numbers is concerned, you could use `strrchr` to find the position of the last colon, and then use `strtok` to split the comma separated values one by one.
Hope it helps.

```
int main() {

    char aSingleLine[] = "1:0;John;23:12,32,44,43\n";
    char* lastColon = strrchr(aSingleLine,':');
    if (lastColon) {
        char* numbers = lastColon+1; // one after the last colon;
        int i=0;
        char *numStr = strtok(numbers,",");
        while(numStr != NULL) {
            int numVal;
            if (sscanf(numStr,"%d",&numVal)==1) {
                printf("%dth value: %d\n", i, numVal);
            }
            else {
                printf("invalid number: %s",numStr);
            }
            i++;
            numStr = strtok(NULL,",");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0th value: 12
1th value: 32
2th value: 44
3th value: 43
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to apply your solution to my problem. :)